# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError with selenium

Tags: java, selenium, path

I know this question is being asked multiple times. But, I cannot find an answer in any of them.

Here are some details of things i'm using.

Firefox version - 63.0

Selenium - selenium-java-3.14

My sample code -

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
```

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class webdriverdemo {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String projectLocation = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","E:\\Proffessional\\FMClarity\\Selenium\\gecko\\geckodriver.exe");  

     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      //Puts an Implicit wait, Will wait for 10 seconds before throwing exception
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

      //Launch website
      driver.navigate().to("http://www.calculator.net/");

}
```

}

But, I'm having the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.<init>(DriverService.java:250)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.<init>(GeckoDriverService.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:125)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:103)
    at webdriverdemo.main(webdriverdemo.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

My path is given like this.

[image]

Can someone tell me what did I do to comeup with this error.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have used jar file for 2.53.1. Problem solved.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is gico-driver is not available in your code

try this

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        //complete path to your project
        String projectLocation = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",your driver full path);
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        //Puts an Implicit wait, Will wait for 10 seconds before throwing exception
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        //Launch website
        driver.navigate().to("http://www.calculator.net/");

    }
```

Comment: can you update your exact code? and have you checked the gico driver and selenium version

Comment: just remove ur // and  you have a complete path of your driver then remove String projectLocation = System.getProperty("user.dir");

Comment: E:/Proffessional/FMClarity/Selenium/gecko/geckodriver.exe or copy ur driver inside your project and set the path using projectLocation

Comment: can you upload your project on github ?? or ur gico driver version